# What wrong with my if condition on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
for k in df.iteritems():
  if df['spam_condition_picture'][k] == 1 and df['spam_condition_desc'][k] == 1:
    df['spam_predict'][k] = 1
  else:
    df['spam_predict'][k] = 0
```

it shown an error like this and there is no tuple in dataframe just 1 or 0

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-a3187d5e09b7> in <module>()
      1 for k in df.iteritems():
----> 2   if (df['spam_condition_picture'][k] == 1) and (df['spam_condition_desc'][k] == 1):
      3     df['spam_predict'][k] = 1
      4   else:
      5     df['spam_predict'][k] = 0

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _get_values_tuple(self, key)
    954 
    955         if not isinstance(self.index, MultiIndex):
--> 956             raise KeyError("key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex")
    957 
    958         # If key is contained, would have returned by now

KeyError: 'key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex'
```

the error shown like this

Comment: error in link above I don't know why picture doesn't show explicitly

Comment: for future posts, post the error in a codeblock instead of printscreens

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: edited. posting error without screenshot

Comment: Did you try checking the value of `k`? Is it as you expect? does it make sense as an index into `df['spam_condition_picture']`? Why or why not?

Comment: `for k in df.iteritems():` will loop over (key, value) pairs, which are of type tuple. It looks like you just want to loop over the index, not the items, of the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off removing your for loop altogether, and use something like the following, to use the power of Pandas and NumPy, and do array-wise assignment:

```
# Create a new column 'spam_predict' with a default value of 0
df['spam_predict'] = 0
# Find out the rows where our combined condition is true
indices = (df['spam_condition_picture'] == 1) & (df['spam_condition_desc'] == 1)
# Assign the new column at those rows to 1
df.loc[indices, 'spam_predict'] = 1
```